# Overhead in networkx reverse function?

Tags: python, graph, reverse, networkx

I have the following code:

```
import networkx

def reverse_graph(g):
    reversed = networkx.DiGraph()
    for e in g.edges():
        reversed.add_edge(e[1], e[0])
    return reversed


g = networkx.DiGraph()

for i in range(500000):
    g.add_edge(i, i+1)

g2 = g.reverse()
g3 = reverse_graph(g)
```

And according to my line profiler I am spending WAY more time reversing the graph using `networkx` (their reverse took about 21 sec, mine took about 7).  The overhead seems high in this simple case, and it's even worse in other code I have with more complex objects.  Is there something happening under the hood of `networkx` I'm not aware of?  This seems like it should be a relatively cheap function.

For reference, here is the [doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.unary.reverse.html) for the `reverse` function

**EDIT:** I also tried running the implementations the other way around (i.e. mine first) to make sure there was no cacheing happening when they created theirs.  Mine was still significantly faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The source code for the reverse method](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/classes/digraph.py#L1251) looks like this:

```
def reverse(self, copy=True):
    """Return the reverse of the graph.

    The reverse is a graph with the same nodes and edges
    but with the directions of the edges reversed.

    Parameters
    ----------
    copy : bool optional (default=True)
        If True, return a new DiGraph holding the reversed edges.
        If False, reverse the reverse graph is created using
        the original graph (this changes the original graph).
    """
    if copy:
        H = self.__class__(name="Reverse of (%s)"%self.name)
        H.add_nodes_from(self)
        H.add_edges_from( (v,u,deepcopy(d)) for u,v,d 
                          in self.edges(data=True) )
        H.graph=deepcopy(self.graph)
        H.node=deepcopy(self.node)
    else:
        self.pred,self.succ=self.succ,self.pred
        self.adj=self.succ
        H=self
    return H
```

So by default, when `copy=True`, not only are the edge nodes reversed,
but also a deepcopy of any edge data is made. Then the graph attributes (held in
`self.graph`) are deepcopied, and then the nodes themselves are deepcopied.
That's a lot of copying that `reverse_graph` does not do.

If you don't deepcopy everything, modifying `g3` could affect `g`.

If you don't need to deepcopy everything, (and if mutating `g` is acceptable) then

```
g.reverse(copy=False)
```

is even faster than

```
g3 = reverse_graph(g)
```

---

```
In [108]: %timeit g.reverse(copy=False)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 359 ns per loop

In [95]: %timeit reverse_graph(g)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.32 s per loop

In [96]: %timeit g.reverse()
1 loops, best of 3: 4.98 s per loop
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  To be clear if I want a NEW graph that is a shallow copy (only copy the edges) I will need my implementation.  Theirs changes the original graph correct?

Comment: Yes, if you *do* want a new graph, then your `reverse_graph` is what you would need. As mentioned before, note that it does drop graph and edge attributes, though.